# Snapping user location in MKMapView to a line/trail

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am working on a trails/maps app that has custom trails mapped out in a region and will aid the user navigate his or her way around some trails in a "foresty" area.

Currently, I am using MKMapView to get the user data/location, and loading the trails as overlays from a KML file. The problem I am having is that while testing the app, I noticed that in some situations the blue dot representing the user position goes off the trail overlays, which is expected since GPS (especially on phones) is not that great, plus some error that might have been obtained when getting the values for the trails to put in the KML file.

I apologize if all of that is a bit confusing, my question is: Is it possible to "snap" the user location (the blue dot that we all love) to a trail/overlay/path that is placed on the map with a specific tolerence? for example, if the blue dot appears to be a few pixels off the trails, then it would be placed right in the middle of the trails. If it is far off, then the user probably walked off the trails, and no snapping will happen to the user's location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I wouldn't bother. If they are just a few pixels off they won't care, but if they are further away then it's important that they know where they are as accurately as possible. They could be lost in the snow and looking for trail markings.
If you do go ahead with that you'll have to abandon the userLocation dot and build our own. Using a LocationManager you can get told every time the device gets new location information and move your custom annotation dot to where you think they should be. More trouble that it's worth IMHO.

Comment: Yup, went with the "don't bother" method!